# How can I automatically hyperlink tag names that are in my post body to the tag page

Tags: tags

I have a number of sports sites with hundreds of thousands of existing news posts. The site also has a custom post type for team and a custom post type for person. I wish to be able to somehow automatically find team names and player names in news post body and hyperlink them to the correct team / player post.

The post names exist with exact player and team names. For example

Lionel Messi  << Player post
Manchester United << Team post
Lionel Messi snubs Manchester United and joins Wolverhampton Wanderers << news post

What approach should I take here?

Bonus karma for this additional consideration. In Drupal the post text filtering actions can be cached against the text filter so that the calculations on the body wouldn't have to be done on every page load.  Are there similar considerations in Wordpress to make this relatively efficient?.

Answer (score 0):

If I am guessing it right, it would be a 2 step process.

1. Store the post title and post id in an assosiative array while publishing the posts (`save_post_POST_TYPE` hook). For ex: `array('Post Title' => 101)` where `101` being the id of the post. I'd use WordPress Options table to store them and quickly retrieve when needed.
2. Now, you can hyperlink (`str_replace`) them on the fly using `the_content` filter or even better save them as hyperlinked when saving the posts.